# Links and hostnames docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services defined in a docker-compose file and am looking to map a service name to a hosts entry so that i can send data to an endpoint in a mongo db service, for example on my host machine I have

```
127.0.0.1 dotcomtest.net
```

if i have a service called `web` and a service called `echo-chamber`, how do i set up my hosts file in my web container (or docker compose file) so that i can send requests to that endpoint, i.e `http://dotcomtest.net/query_string?`

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want container to contact dotcomtest.net which is on your host machine? Which OS are you using?

Comment: yes (i think so), though i thought the two containers would be on their own network so to speak, so i thought it would be a case of communication between the two containers. Im using MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible when they both run on same network. So best is to put them both in a `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx1:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
  nginx2:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - dotcomtest.net
```

When I up this composition and go to the `nginx1` container using

```
docker-compose exec nginx1 bash
```

And execute below commands

```
root@cabf18b17f34:/# apt update && apt install -y curl
root@cabf18b17f34:/# curl http://dotcomtest.net
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see my nginx1 container has access to nginx2

Comment: thats great, looks like it's all working :-) not totally 100% on how this works though and can't find `network aliases` in the docks

Comment: In `docker-compose` you get a default network, which is equivalent to `docker network create <name>` and each of your container gets associated with this network automatically. Now you can specify aliases names to these networks. When two containers run in the same network they are addressable using their <ID> and <NAME> which in our case is the service name `nginx1` and `nginx2`